# gatsby multiple collection routes for multiple markdown folders

Tags: reactjs, graphql, markdown, gatsby

I have two markdown collection routes which I want to apply to two different sets of markdowns separated by subfolders.

My folder structure is as follows

```
appfolder
  content
    projects
      project1.md
      project2.md
    article
      article1.md
      article2.md
  src
    pages
      projects
        {MarkdownRemark.frontmatter__slug}.js 
      articles
        {MarkdownRemark.frontmatter__slug}.js
```

The content of projects/{MarkdownRemark.frontmatter__slug}.js is as follows

```
import React from 'react';
import Layout from "../../components/Layout";
import Nav from "../../components/Nav";
import PageHeader from "../../components/PageHeader";
import Footer from "../../components/Footer";
import SimpleReactLightbox from 'simple-react-lightbox'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
const ProjectPage = ({data}) => {
    const fm = data.markdownRemark.frontmatter;
    const html = data.markdownRemark.html;
    return (
        <SimpleReactLightbox>
        <Layout pageTitle={fm.title}>
            <Nav />
            <PageHeader title={fm.title} />
            <Footer />
        </Layout>
        </SimpleReactLightbox>
    );
};


export const query = graphql`
query($id: String!) {
    markdownRemark(id: { eq: $id },fileAbsolutePath: {regex: "/(projects)/" }) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        slug
        title
        summary
        icon
      }
    }
}
`

export default ProjectPage;
```

But GraphiQL shows that the pages are generated for all md files. How do I restrict each collection route to respective subfolder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem. It seems like there are no ready-made solutions for your current organization of `src/pages`. But after running through the discussions on Gatsby, I found there are some workarounds, though I think it's a bit inconvenient.

Like [this comment](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/26375#discussioncomment-239221) said:

> If your source nodes contain something like `category: "article" | "blog"`, you could generate separate routes with file nested in
> `category` directory like `/{SourceNode.category}/{SourceNode.slug}.tsx`.
>
> If your source node does not contain such a category field, then you
> can append it to the nodes in [onCreateNode hook](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-node/#onCreateNode), or create entirely
> new nodes for your purposes

In your case, if you can add a `category` field to the frontmatter in your `.md` files, you can change your organization of `src` to

```
appfolder
  content
    projects
      project1.md
      project2.md
    article
      article1.md
      article2.md
  src
    templates
      project-template.js
      article-template.js
    pages
      {MarkdownRemark.frontmatter__category}
        {MarkdownRemark.frontmatter__slug}.js
```

Then `projects/{MarkdownRemark.frontmatter__slug}.js` goes to `templates/project-template.js` and the article one is similar.

Now in your `{MarkdownRemark.frontmatter__slug}.js` file, you can forward the data queried by GraphQL to the corresponding template.

```
// {MarkdownRemark.frontmatter__slug}.js
const GeneratedPage = ({ data }) => {
  const templates = {
    project: <ProjectTemplate data={data} />,
    article: <ArticleTemplate data={data} />,
  };

  return templates[data.MarkdownRemark.frontmatter.category];
};
```

If it's not possible to add the `category` field into the `.md` file, make use of the [`createNodeField` API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/actions/#createNodeField) to programmatically add it to `MarkdownRemark` nodes in `gatsby-node.js`. It maybe something like this:

```
// gatsby-node.js
exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions;
  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const value = ...; // something mapping the directory of node to certain catecory
    createNodeField({
      name: 'category',
      node,
      value,
    });
  }
};
```

Hope this can be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Think your issues falls at `fileAbsolutePath` for the regex.

Change `(projects)` to just `projects`

Comment: Tried it and that does not solve the problem.

Comment: Can you add your gatsby-config and how you're bringing it in?

Answer (score 0):

In that cases, I think the easiest approach is adding a "key" value in your frontmatter to make the filter. For example:

```
---
key: article
title: Test Title
anotherField: Another field value
---
The body of the markdown
```

*Note: change `key: article` for `key: projects` when needed*

Then, in your GraphQL query use the `filter` with something like:

```
export const query = graphql`
query($id: String!) {
    markdownRemark(id: { eq: $id }, filter: { frontmatter: { key: { eq: "article" },  
          }
        },, ) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        slug
        title
        summary
        icon
      }
    }
}
`
```

Tweak it as you need and check the availability of the filters in the `localhost:8000/___graphql` playground.